# I'm trying to let a user who has been assigned something be able to view it with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I've tried searching an answer for this and I can't realy find the one that fits what I'm looking for.

I'm making a small web application that allows an admin to create course material and a test, that a user will be assigned.

What I am trying to figure out, is how a user, who has been assigned a course, can access that course by clicking a button.

I have created one table which stores the user information, with a user ID being a primary key.  I have a course table, which stores all materials and the course's test, with a course id being that table's primary key.

I made a third table which is an assigned_courses table, it contains two foreign keys.  One referencing the user id from the user table, and one referencing the course id on the course table.

I've inserted a few images to show what you mean.

I can't quite figure out the Sql syntax to pull course materials and test based on the assigned_course table.

All feedback appreciated. This is the two foreign keys that reference the user id (id) and the course id(u_id)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what column names you have so I used `*` instead. You can use `JOIN` (AKA `INNER JOIN`) to link the tables together. You join on the primary keys of the 2 tables.

> I have created one table which stores the user information, with a
>   user ID being a primary key. I have a course table, which stores all
>   materials and the course's test, with a course id being that table's
>   primary key.

I used `id` for your user table and `course_id` for the course table. Change as needed.

Find all courses for a given user.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM course a
JOIN assigned_course b ON a.course_id = b.id
WHERE b.u_id = :userId
;
```

Find all users for a given course.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM user a
JOIN assigned_course b ON a.id = b.u_id
WHERE b.id = :courseId
;
```

**EDIT #1 - Subquery without JOIN**

> Thanks for your feedback, as I stated above, I was hoping to avoid a
>   join.

I highly recommend you learn joins. They are essential when you need to query more than 1 table. In this case, you can use a sub-query to find matching courses for a user but you won't be able to access that user data at the same time; that is the power of a join. I'll include a final example underneath showing how to get courses and user data at the same time.

Find all courses for a given user (using sub-query)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM course a
WHERE course_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM assigned_course b 
    WHERE u_id = :userId)
;
```

Final example showing courses related to users (many-to-many)

```
SELECT * -- You now have access to a, b, and c data
FROM course a
JOIN assigned_course b ON a.course_id = b.id -- joined by PKs
JOIN user c ON c.id = b.u_id -- joined by PKs
WHERE c.id = :userId
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, as I stated above, I was hoping to avoid a join.  I appreciate your time and feedback though and will try it!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to use SQL Join syntax which goes as follows:

```
select column1, column2, column3 etc...
from table1
join course on table1.id = course.id 
join assigned_course on table1.id = assigned_course.id
```

replace the `column1,2,3` etc with the actual column names, and replace the `foreign_key_name` with the actual name of the foreign key in the sub-table and the same for the `user_primary_key`

you can find some other examples of mysql joins [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

as far as how to implement them into your html or php file, that is a very different question and would require knowing alot more about how your code is setup in the form

a place that is pretty user friendly is that might help with pulling the data is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) just make sure you are aware of using [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for your code

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was hoping to avoid joins, can't ever get my head around them.  I will try that.  Thank you.